# Qt Combobox Model Using SQLite

Tags: qt, sqlite, qcombobox, qtsql, qsqltablemodel

With Sq-lite, how can I set a model for the combo-box that has two table columns added together (ie surName +' '+ firstName)...with MS SQL Server I simply use a view.

When I tried with Sq Lite...nope! all other widgets (ie.QLineEdit and QDateEdits) loose their content and only combo-boxes display please Help!

Edit: 
Using QSqlRelationalModel the QWidgetDataMapper does not work on my form. All widgets are null except the comb-boxes using the default delegate

```
parInd = model->fieldIndex("stPar");
model->setRelation(parInd,QSqlRelation("allParents", "parID", "parName")); 
QSqlTableModel *parModel = model->relationModel(parInd); 
ui->stParent->setModel(parModel); 
ui->stParent->setModelColumn(parModel->fieldIndex("parName"));
```

The allParents is a view saved on my sqlite db When I change reference table to tblParents(the base table) all widgets are ok with data...the problem is the parent field displays only firstname yet I need the fullname. How can I work around this!

Comment: Please post a minimal example demonstrating this issue. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11021486/1329652) could serve as some inspiration for how a single-file test case using sqlite can look like.

Comment: What's wrong with using view in sqlite?